# Image compression with specific block size and max run length

Tags: python, binary, compression, run-length-encoding

I need to write two functions called `compress(S)` and `decompress(S)`  that take a binary string S of length less than or equal to 64 as input and return another binary string as output. The output binary string should be a run-length encoding of the input string.

```
COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE = 5

MAX_RUN_LENGTH = 2 ** COMPRESSED_BLOCK_SIZE - 1

>>>compress( 64*'0' )
'1111100000111110000000010'

>>>uncompress('1111100000111110000000010')
'64*0'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: (Hint: questions end with a question mark.)